# Dynamic click event listener

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

I am having some issues with a dynamic event listener loop that looks like this:

```
profiles.forEach(function(item, i) {

    document.getElementById("test-" + i).addEventListener("click", function() {

      chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {

        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url:  `https://example.com/profile/${item.platform}/${item.region}/${item.username}`})

      });

    })

})
```

Lets say that the profiles array has a length of 2, then it's only the last element that gets an "addEventListener" function even though I am saying that the ID's test-0 and test-1 should get an attached event listener since the loop runs two times with the index of 0 and 1.

I read something about closures but since this already is within a function compared to a normal for loop, I am not sure what the problem could be.

I would appreciate any help given!

Comment: You haven't stated the problem. what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Oh, the problem is that it's only the last id (test-1) that gets an attached event listener, whilst the first one in the loop (test-0) doesn't. There's no actual error in the console though. @Harshakj89

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/6kurpxum/) seems to work just fine.
Are you sure your document.getElementById("test-" +i) gets you the right elements?

Comment: @afterburn I do get both test-0 and test-1 when logging them to the console. I can see that your example works though, I am not sure why I am not getting the same results

Comment: Alright that's strange, when you simply put a console log instead of the chrome stuff, do those messages appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I left out a very essential part in the loop, forgot to add to the post by mistake when trying to solve the problem.

The links test-0 and test-1 were appended to the DOM in the loop at the second row.

```
profiles.forEach(function(item, i) {
content.innerHTML += item.column + item.html + "</div>"

document.getElementById("test-" + i).addEventListener("click", function() {

  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {

    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url:  `https://example.com/profile/${item.platform}/${item.region}/${item.username}`})

    });

  })
})
```

So I created a seperate for-loop after the first one to attach the click events to the links.

**My bad for not including that, thanks for the help guys!**